# VScode Terminal giving output: 'g++' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, g++, mingw

I first installed the Mingw from https://osdn.net/projects/mingw/downloads/68260/mingw-get-setup.exe/ and downloaded all the packages and set C:\MinGW\bin as a new path in my Environmental System Variables. I open my command prompt and type "g++ --version" which gives me the output "g++ (MinGW.org GCC-8.2.0-5) 8.2.0" So I believe this means so far I'm follow the correct path.

My problem arises while I'm in VSCode trying to compile a basic hello world file. In the terminal I input "g++ main.cpp" however this gets me the output "'g++' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file." Does this have to do with how one of my .json files are set up? I've included the following c_cpp_poperties, launch, and task code.

Thank you.

c_cpp_properties.json:

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Win32",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**"
        ],
        "defines": [
            "_DEBUG",
            "UNICODE",
            "_UNICODE"
        ],
        "compilerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe",
        "cStandard": "c11",
        "cppStandard": "c++17",
        "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64"
    }
],
"version": 4}
```

launch.json:

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "C++ Compiler",
        "type": "cppvsdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "C:/MinGW/bin",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": true
    },
]}
```

task.json:

```
{
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
  {
    "label": "build hello world",
    "type": "shell",
    "command": "C:/MinGW/bin/g++",
    "args": [
      "-g",
      "-o",
      "helloworld",
      "helloworld.cpp"
    ],
    "group": {
      "kind": "build",
      "isDefault": true
    }
  }
]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
    "compilerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe",
```

With

```
    "compilerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe",
```